# finding just full words in a python string

Tags: python

Basically it all comes down to finding just the fullword, not matching also a substring thereof.

I have phrases like:

texto = "hello today is the first day of working week" and what I wanted to do is to split that phrase into words to see if any matched fullwords that I have obtained from a sql query, like this:

```
sql = "select keyword from keywords"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for result in results:
            keywords.append(result)
```

so there I have a tuple of keywords.

So, yes, of course, you would split the phrase like this:

```
for word in texto.split():
    if word in keywords.__str__():
        print ("keyword %s detected in texto" % (word))
```

but while that does indeed find me words, it also "finds" me things that I would have not wanted or expected (a substring of a word):

I know that in PHP you would do something like this:

```
if (preg_match("/\b$search\b/", texto)):
            {print "word found"}
```

and I ve read quite a few discussions on this at SO. Some people say that you just do split, (but that is what I have done), others say use this:

in isn't how it's done.

```
>>> re.search(r'\babc\b', 'abc123')
>>> re.search(r'\babc\b', 'abc 123')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1146780>
```

is this latest example the way to do it? according to the shell interpreter it would match the second row.

Comment: Is the stuff about SQL relevant to the question, or could we remove it and just give a particular example input to the text processing problem?

Comment: Did you read the docs for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)? It returns a match object if it found something and `None` otherwise. This is exactly what you're seeing. `re.search(r'\babc\b', 'abc123') is None` and `re.search(r'\babc\b', 'abc 123') is not None` should both be true.

Comment: what is the output of `keywords.__str__()`? If it is one string containing all keywords, is should be `.split()` as well. BTW: why do you use the __str__() at all? just removing it might fix the issue...

Comment: Assuming your keywords list is really a list of single words, remove the `.__str__()` as this is giving you the string representation of the list. And then the `in` statement searches for your words in that string instead of in the list.

Comment: yes the sql is relevant because I think it brings me objects not words, that is why I had to use the .__str__() to make a string representation of that object that could then be workable when searching for words in a phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't see why split() should not work. The issue is the `.__str__()` (which I don't see any need for). It creates one single string in which the keywords are searched - and then it will find substrings as well.

The following is working for me:

```
texto = "hello today is the first day of working week"
keywords = ["is", "day", "week", "work", "sun"]

for keyword in keywords:
    print("keyword", keyword, end=" ")
    if keyword in texto.split():
        print("found.")
    else:
        print("not found")
```

`work` and `sun` should not match, `work` is a substring in the text, `sun` is not in the text.

Output is

```
keyword is found.
keyword day found.
keyword week found.
keyword work not found
keyword sun not found
```

Comment: thank you everybody, it seems that the .__str__() was the reason of the problems..

Comment: Keywords is a list of tuples, that is [('Europe',), ('Spain',), ('France',)]

Comment: just change `keyword` to `keyword[0]` to get the string from the tuple. BTW: If there are performance issues, you could move the `.split()` out of the loop by creating a new split list before the loop.